# Retrieve specific cell, when another cell is largest, 2nd largest and 3rd largest

Tags: excel

I've made a sheet, where 3 other cells shows the largest, second largest and third largest number. `=LARGE(B2:L2;COUNTIF(B2:L2;MAX(B2:L2)))`

Is it possible to make the cell show another cell, when another cell is the largest number?

The whole idea is to count votes, and then show three names, that has gotten the most votes, in different categories.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample input and the expected output for it?

Comment: Can I put excell into the question?

Comment: You can put formulas in and add a screenshot of your sheet. Or just explain your sheet contents by using the `code` formatting option and try to achieve some table-like layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

Although I do not completely understand the formula you provided (you count how many times the maximum value appears and use that as index?), in general the approach is the following:

```
=INDEX(1:1, MATCH(<max_votes>, 2:2, 0))
```

The MATCH function looks for the value (or the value of a cell reference) in the given area. So you tell it to look for the cell where the maximum votes are (that you just found out using your formula). This column reference is given to the INDEX formula that now uses the cell in row 1 (given by argument 1:1), the column is determined by the MATCH function.

So e.g. if you max vote amount is in column C, the INDEX function will retrieve the value of C1.

Comment: Perfect. Sorry for bad explanation, but that was exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Glad I could help you :) Take care that if one of the votes you are looking for appears more than once you need to do extra work, e.g. check how often the value appears (COUNTIF) and alter the lookup range of MATCH so that it starts to look for the next appearance only in the columns after the first match.